# background color is not applied?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am stuck with a problem , when am trying to give background colour on my top bar its won't applied , I tried lots of time but still its won't working, please try to fix my error

[image]

This is my simple top bar code

> topbar.html

```
<div class="header-top bg-dark" style="background-color: black;">
        <div class="container-fluid bg-dark" style="background-color: black;">
            <div class="left-side float-left ml-5">
                <p>Search</p>
                <p style="text-indent: 20px;">About Us</p>
                <p style="text-indent: 20px;">Contact Us</p>
            </div>
            <div class="right-side float-right mr-5">
                <p>Login</p>
                <p style="text-indent: 20px;">Register</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Two problems:

1. Your `float` is breaking the layout, so you need to add the class `.clearfix` to the parent to fix it.
2. The class `bg-dark` adds `!important`, so if you want to override it, you need to do like `background-color: black !important;`

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="header-top bg-dark" style="background-color: black !important;">
  <div class="container-fluid bg-dark clearfix" style="background-color: black !important;">
    <div class="left-side float-left ml-5">
      <p>Search</p>
      <p style="text-indent: 20px;">About Us</p>
      <p style="text-indent: 20px;">Contact Us</p>
    </div>
    <div class="right-side float-right mr-5">
      <p>Login</p>
      <p style="text-indent: 20px;">Register</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

i think because you are using inline css, you could do like this
open another file for css and give it the
css file

mycolor{ background-color: black;}

Answer (score 0):

you are getting other color because of the class you are using **bg-dark** so either you remove that from div class names or replace your codes with following lines :

```
<div class="header-top bg-dark" style="background-color: black !important; ">
  <div class="container-fluid bg-dark clearfix" style="background-color: black !important;">
```

**OR**

```
<div class="header-top" style="background-color: black; ">
  <div class="container-fluid clearfix" style="background-color: black;">
```

this !important will overwrite **bg-dark** attribute of the div class

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using inline styles for multiple paragraph or other repeating elements, you can simply put `<styles>` tag and add your styles there so it will be more readable or put your styles in different file and link it to your html.

As for the code, you can try the `!important` ending if the style is not applied, also you need to change the color of your text

Here is an example

```
<div class="header-top bg-dark">
<div class="container-fluid bg-dark clearfix">
  <div class="left-side float-left ml-5">
    <p>Search</p>
    <p>About Us</p>
    <p>Contact Us</p>
  </div>
  <div class="right-side float-right mr-5">
    <p>Login</p>
    <p>Register</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
<style>
  .header-top, .container-fluid {
      background-color: black !important;
  }
  p {
      text-indent: 20px;
      color: white;
  }
</style>
```